# Which of the following sentences is clear?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say 'Talk about a different typical characteristic between men and women'? or we have to say 'Talk about a typical characteristic of men which is different from that of women'? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The first doesn't make sense. The second does.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentance should be *TalkING about THE differeNCE BETWEEN typicalLY FOUND characteristicS OF men and women'?* TO Be  grammatically correct.